# Android - BufferOverflowException while encoding aac audio using mediacodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, aac

I am trying to encode some audio streams with `aac` codec using `Mediacodec`. For this I'm using this implementation [google cts ExtractDecodeEncodeMusTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/refs/heads/android10-mainline-a-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java).

For some aac files it throws `BufferOverflowException` after encoding some frames. To be more precise, it throws exception at line no 1030, `encoderInputBuffer.put(decoderOutputBuffer);`.

I am configuring the `outputAudioFormat` as following:

```
MediaFormat outputAudioFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(
        inputAudioFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME),
        inputAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE),
        inputAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT)            
);
outputAudioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, outputAudioBitRate);
```

I'm completely clueless about how to resolve this. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

**Stacktrace with some log:**

```
W/MPEG4Writer: Timed-out waiting for video track to reach final audio timestamp !
D/MPEG4Writer: Video track source stopping
    Video track source stopped
    Video track stopped. Stop source
    Duration from tracks range is [0, 125135] us
    Stopping writer thread
D/MPEG4Writer: 0 chunks are written in the last batch
D/MPEG4Writer: Writer thread stopped
W/System.err: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:611)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:256)
```

- **Device:** Xiaomi POCO x3
- **OS:** Android 10

**Sample file's info that causing the overflow:**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Sample/sample.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        creation_time   : 2017-11-10T09:36:00.000000Z
        encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
      Duration: 01:58:17.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2726 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 1920x804 (1920x816) [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67], 2497 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 11988 tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-11-10T09:36:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-11-10T09:36:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

**Update:**

Log says `audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.size= 12288 || encoderInputBuffer.limit()= 4096` before throwing the overflow exception.

And log of `decoderOutputAudioFormat`:

```
audio decoder: output format changed: {sample-rate=48000, pcm-encoding=2, mime=audio/raw, channel-count=6}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this but have you tried to split a frame into several parts that will fit to buffer's capacity?

Comment: I didn't knew if it was possible to split a frame. Can you please share any resource on how to do that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more information, such as what is the source of the audio and how you configured the encoder.

Comment: @dev.bmax I have duplicated the test implementation linked in the question. The audio stream came along with a movie. I've attached media info with the question. Please check now.

Comment: @MdYeamin Did you copy `OUTPUT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_HZ` and `OUTPUT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_COUNT` from the test as-is?

Comment: @dev.bmax Thank you for your time. I am configuring the output audio format from input audio. So, `OUTPUT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_HZ` and `OUTPUT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_COUNT` is not same as the test. I've added the implementation. Please check again.

Comment: @MdYeamin can you see the `decoderOutputVideoFormat` in the log? What is the value for pcm-encoding?

Comment: @MdYeamin Also please log the value of `audioDecoderOutputBufferInfo.size` and `encoderInputBuffer.limit()`.

Comment: @dev.bmax I've added the log info.

Comment: @MdYeamin Sorry, I meant `decoderOutputAudioFormat` (not video). It should be: "audio decoder: output format changed"

Comment: @dev.bmax No problem, I've updated accordingly. Please check.

Comment: One more thing please, can you log `inputAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT)` ?

Comment: The log says channel count of input audio is 6. I'm getting this overflow for also some audios witch only 2 channels.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferOverflowException` happens when there is no agreement between the producer (e.g. decoder) and the consumer (e.g. encoder) about the size of the buffers.

When you configure the encoder, it allocates input buffers based on the information in the `MediaFormat` that it receives. The standard packet size for AAC is 1024 frames. Frame size = sample size * channel count. PCM 16-bit (default encoding) uses 2 bytes per sample.

So, based on the information you gave it, the encoder is supposed to allocate buffers of size 1024 * 2 * 6 = 12288 bytes. However, in your case it actually allocates only 4096 bytes. So I assume that the encoder ignored the `channel-count` property and defaulted to 2 channels. Possibly, it printed some warning to the log.

One thing that you can still do is to manually reduce the number of channels in every frame to at most 2. You will need to allocate a new buffer and copy the decoded data into it while skipping every Nth sample. And don't forget to `rewind` the resulting buffer before you pass it to the encoder.

Comment: I have tried to set audio channel count 2 and sample rate 44100, but no luck yet. Still getting the overflow.

Comment: This is not a configuration change, you need to compress the decoded buffer down to the size of the encoder buffer. And when the sizes match there will be no overflow.